# Sql query to select jobs where start and target city are in my city list

Tags: sql, inner-join

Every driver has a list of cities where he travel between them (Table "mycities").

I want to show him a list of jobs (from JOBS table) where start city and target city are in his list. I am confused how to join tables to check both start city and target city at same time:

If I use **OR** operator, the result does not cover both cities and if I use **AND** operator, the result would be empty:

```
select * from jobs inner join mycities on 
(mycities.city=jobs.startcity or mycities.city=jobs.targetcity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd join the city table twice, once for the start city once for the target one. Use table aliases to tell them apart.

```
select * 
from jobs 
inner join mycities start on start.city = jobs.startcity
inner join mycities target on target.city = jobs.targetcity;
```

And in case you don't want to select any data from the city table, you wouldn't join at all, but use `IN` or `EXISTS` instead:

```
select * 
from jobs 
where startcity in (select city from mycities)
and targetcity in (select city from mycities);
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea which one is faster in large amount of data?

Comment: No. Anyway, I would always use the straight-forward query as long as there are no performance issues. So if you don't need any data from the city table, then don't join, but only look it up with `IN`. Some databases with a weak optimizer work better with `EXISTS` though: `where exists (select * from mycities where mycities.city = jobs.startcity)`. So use `EXISTS` when `IN` is too slow or in case you like it better. Only if you still have performance issues use a join.

Answer (score 1):

```
(mycities.city=jobs.startcity or mycities.city=jobs.targetcity)
```

This means that startcity **OR** targetcity is in table "mycities".

```
(mycities.city=jobs.startcity and mycities.city=jobs.targetcity)
```

This means that startcity **AND** targetcity is in table "mycities", but

```
a=b and a=c mean also b=c
```

...so you will get only this jobs, where startcity = targetcity and that's why result is empty.

You probably want to use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE 
   startcity IN (SELECT * FROM mycities) AND
   targetcity IN (SELECT * FROM mycities);
```